# ParseKit: What built-in Productions should I use in my Grammars?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, parsekit

I just started using ParseKit to explore language creation and perhaps build a small toy DSL. However, the current SVN trunk from Google is throwing a `-[PKToken intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...` when parsing this grammar:

```
@start = identifier ;
identifier = (Letter | '_') | (letterOrDigit | '_') ;
letterOrDigit = Letter | Digit ;
```

Against this input:

```
foo
```

Clearly, I am missing something or have incorrectly configured my project. What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

First, see the [ParseKit Tokenization docs](http://parsekit.com/tokenization.html).

Basically, ParseKit can work in one of two modes: Let's call them `Tokens Mode` and `Chars Mode`. (There are no formal names for these two modes, but perhaps there should be.)

`Tokens Mode` is more popular by far. Virtually every example you will find of using ParseKit will show how to use `Tokens Mode`. I believe all of the documentation on http://parsekit.com is using `Tokens Mode`. ParseKit's grammar feature (that you are using in your example only works in `Tokens Mode`).

`Chars Mode` is a very little-known feature of ParseKit. I've never had anyone ask about it before.

So the differences in the modes are:

- In `Tokens Mode`, the ParseKit Tokenizer emits **multi-char** tokens (like Words, Symbols, Numbers, QuotedStrings etc) which are then parsed by the ParseKit parsers you create (programmatically or via grammars).
- In `Chars Mode`, the ParseKit Tokenizer always emits **single-char** tokens which are then parsed by the ParseKit parsers you create programmatically. (grammars don't currently work with this mode as this mode is not popular).

You could use `Chars Mode` to implement Regular Expresions which parse on a char-by-char basis.

---

For your example, you should be ignoring `Chars Mode` and just use `Tokens Mode`. The following Built-in Productions are for `Chars Mode` only. Do not use them in your grammars:

```
(PK)Letter
(PK)Digit
(PK)Char
(PK)SpecificChar
```

Notice how all of those Productions sound like they match individual chars. That's because they do.

Your example above should probably look like:

```
@start = identifier;
identifier = Word; // by default Words start with a-zA-Z_ and contain -0-9a-zAZ_'
```

Keep in mind the Productions in your grammars (parsers like `identifier`) will be working on **Tokens** already emitted from ParseKit's Tokenizer. Not individual chars.

IOW: by the time your grammar goes to work parsing input, the input has already been tokenized into Tokens of type Word, Number, Symbol, QuotedString, etc.

Here are all of the Built-in Productions available for use in your Grammar:

```
Word
Number 
Symbol
QuotedString
Comment
Any
S // Whitespace. only available when @preservesWhitespaceTokens=YES. NO by default.
```

Also:

```
DelimitedString('start', 'end', 'allowedCharset')
/xxx/i // RegEx match
```

There are also operators for composite parsers:

```
  // Sequence
| // Alternation
? // Optional
+ // Multiple
* // Repetition
~ // Negation
& // Intersection
- // Difference
```

Comment: Ok, so the take-away is that the PK default of `Word` already has the implicit definition of `identifier`, therefor making my definition redundant and difficult to resolve in PK's Token Mode? So simply changing `identifier = Word ;` should be enough to get me back on track? Thanks!