# When ParseKit tries to recognize my Grammar, it enters an infinite loop. What's wrong?

Tags: objective-c, parsekit

Hi I am creating grammar for some formula which is using recursion. The formula is much more complicated but for now I test only some part of it. After calling parse method it crashes on allMatchesFor method. The stack trace is full of allMatchesFor invocations so it looks like it is in infinite loop
Where is the problem. Is it in my grammar construction logic or else ? How can I accomplish similar thing to avoid this crash

My grammar is like:

```
@start = formula;
formula = valueTypeResult;
valueTypeResult = (value | concept | arithmeticStatement);
arithmeticStatement = valueTypeResult (arithmeticOperator valueTypeResult)+;
value = 'V';
concept = 'C';
arithmeticOperator = 'A';
```

Can you please tell me how to create grammars which use recursion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

ParseKit has no problem with recursion, but your grammar is incorrect. This is more of a BNF grammar problem than a ParseKit problem.

Here's the correct version of what I believe you are attempting with your grammar above:

```
@start = formula;
formula = arithmeticStatement;
arithmeticStatement = valueTypeResult (arithmeticOperator valueTypeResult)+;
valueTypeResult = (value | concept);
value = 'V';
concept = 'C';
arithmeticOperator = 'A';
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work for me. I give string 'VAC' to parse and it should parse without errors. One value(V) followed by arithmetic operator(A) and concept at the end(C).

Comment: You must put spaces (of some kind) between the Characters. If you are using ParseKit *grammars*, then the input string is tokenized. `VAC` is a single `Word` token. *Not* 3 individual characters. I suggest reading the ParseKit Tokenization docs (http://parsekit.com/tokenization.html). And my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792980/parsekit-what-built-in-productions-should-i-use-in-my-grammars

Comment: Thank you for your hints. I would like also to ask you one thing. Can I set parsekit not to look from the beginning of string but try to match entire string something like greedy mode in regexp ?

Comment: If you would like to thank me, please mark my answer as correct. :)

Comment: Thank you Todd. I marked your answer as correct. Could you reply to the question in my last comment ?

Comment: One little request. Could you update RegexKitLite classes in ParseKit/src

Comment: I don't understand your first question. Please post it as a fully detailed new question and I will try to answer. Re: RegexKit: ParseKit is open source. Make the change and send me a diff.

Comment: I created new question as you said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939642/parsekit-greedy-matching-mode I also sent you a diff so you could update master branch. Thanks